# Django IntegrityError NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_solution.puzzle_id

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

So I am creating a puzzling app, where you can submit Solutions to puzzles, and add Comments to Solutions.

Here are my models:

```
class Solution(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    puzzle = models.ForeignKey(
        Puzzle,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()
    points = models.IntegerField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    solution = models.ForeignKey(
        Solution,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am trying to implement an Add Comment feature using standard Django Forms. Here is my views:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        # Add Comment feature
        form = AddCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.solution = Solution.objects.get(id=solutionID)
            ## Debugging ##
            print(comment.title)
            print(comment.content)
            print('Solution:')
            print(comment.solution)
            print('Puzzle: ')
            print(comment.solution.puzzle)
            print(comment.solution.puzzle.id)
            ###############
            comment.save()    
            messages.success(request, 'Solution was created successfully!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("solutions", kwargs={'puzzleID': puzzleID}))
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'There are some errors on the form.')
            return render(request, "add_solution.html", {
                "form": form,
            })
```

And of course my forms:

```
class AddCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddCommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Title'
        self.fields['content'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Content'

    title = forms.CharField()
    content = forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows": 6,}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Solution
        fields = ['title', 'content']
```

When I try to use this feature, Django gives me the error stated above. My understanding of the error is that Django thinks I haven't provided the Comment a valid Solution. However, you will notice that I have used print statements in my view to make sure that I am passing in valid values, so I know for a fact that I am passing a valid Solution, which is linked to a valid Puzzle.

So I cannot seem to understand the error message. Someone please help!

Thank you :)

Comment: As a side note: it's generally not a good idea to name a field "datetime". It is both a reserved word for SQL and the name of a Python standard library module. `last_modified` or `posted_at` are alternatives that better describe the intention of the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you have called your form AddCommentForm, it actually declares its model as Solution rather than Comment in the Meta class. Therefore, Django thinks you are trying to create a new Solution, which requires a Puzzle.

I assume that is a mistake and you meant to use Comment there.